# Font-family causes one pixel drawing problem in Chrome

Tags: html, css, chromium

I'm trying to show a simple tab-menu on a web page. I'm using a pretty basic and well-used pattern, which is working fine except that when I test the page in Chrome (well, Chromium but afaik it's the same) I see a 1-pixel wide artifact that I can't seem to mask.

Here's the test code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>One pixel menu bug</title>
  <style>
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
}
h1 {margin-bottom: 1em}
#menu {
  padding-top: .3em;
  padding-bottom: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  background: black;
  font-size: 1em;
  margin-top: 0.5em;
}
#menu ul {
  list-style: none;
  border: 0 none;
  padding: 0;
  margin-left: 2em;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
#menu li {
  display: inline;
  margin-right: .15em;
  background-color: white;
}
#menu li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #99a;
  padding: 0px 12px;

}
#menu a.selected {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: black;
  border-bottom: 2px solid white;
}
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Site title here</h1>
  <div id="header">
    <div id="menu">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Are we not men?</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="selected">We are Devo</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
</body>
</html>
```

and the result I see with Chrome (left) and Firefox (right):

[image]

Removing the font-family line of the style declaration makes the problem disappear, but I don't want to do that for the main site. Explanations as to what's going on, or suggestions for work-arounds welcome!

Comment: fyi:it shows the black line in Opera too

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not all browsers will render the font exactly the same height. Besides, you're mixing pixel measurements with point measurements (em), which can cause rounding problems too.

I think you can easily fix this by specifying either a line height, or an exact height for the menu item. And/or set their position relative to the bottom of the menu. As far as I can tell you do neighter, so their exact position is now entirely based on the height of the rendered font.

Comment: Thanks GolezTrol. Setting `position: relative; bottom: 0` didn't change anything, but the `line-height` setting was necessary. I also needed to set `background-color: white` on the `#menu li a` rule.

Comment: Setting bottom to 0 when position is relative, doesn't change a bit. You shift the button 0 px from the position where it would have been. :) It will work if you set position to absolute (provided the parent has a position too!). But fixing it by setting the line-height is probably better. Else, you would have the missing pixel on top of the item. ;-)

Comment: Doh, yes. One day, all the nuances of the CSS box model will sink in to my brain properly :) I didn't want to use position: absolute because I think that will stop the menu wrapping if it happens to be on a small screen.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have a line-height problem - sans serif fonts have different hights/glyphs than serif/mono ?

Try set line-height as well as font-family - 1.5em - 12 px font = 18px line-height ?

Just guessing ...

Comment: Thanks 639175, setting the `line-height` was helpful.